# How to read TCP client inputStream until a specific character c#

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, tcpclient

I want to read TCP data coming from a nodeMCU until a specific character ("!") in UWP. A function of the TCP Client is the recieve function below:

```
public async void Receive()
{
    try
    {
        DataReader _reader = new DataReader(_socket.InputStream);
        uint header = await _reader.LoadAsync(4);

        if (header == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        int len = _reader.ReadInt32();
        uint lenBytes = await _reader.LoadAsync((uint)len);

        string message = _reader.ReadString(lenBytes);

        OnReceived(_socket, message);

        Receive();
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        OnException(this, x);
    }
}
```

It should be able to read the stream till "!".

Comment: A few issues here: You shouldn't be using `async void` if this is not an event handler (or some other very few exceptions), but `async Task`. Then you are mixing async/await with Events. Better `await Receive()` and have it return the message. This will probably save you from some headaches.

Comment: Don;t try to read to a character.  Instead read all data available into a string.  Then flush beginning of string until you find start of data.  TCP there is no guarantee that all the data will come in one chunk.  So you need to both flush data at beginning and wait until you get all the data.  The end of data may either be and End character or a byte count following the start character.

Comment: You say you want to read the stream until `!` (i.e., using a delimiter as a message boundary), but your code is using a header (i.e., using length prefixing as a message boundary). Which kind of [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) is your protocol actually using?